# UserPrincipal.GetAuthorizationGroups receiving null groups

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory, .net-7.0

I've implemented Windows Auhtentication login to my .NET 7 application, but I'm stuck on resolving groups.

Sometimes, some of elements of the result of `UserPrincipal.GetAuthorizationGroups` is just null, but count of the result `UserPrincipal.GetAuthorizationGroups` is always the same.

I've tried to debug this issue and I've noticed that executing `UserPrincipal.GetAuthorizationGroups().ToList()` in the watch on breakpoint set on the `Debug.WriteLine` in the code below in Visual Studio gets all groups.
Like there is some delay to get data from Active Directory and I'm receiving not complete results.

My current code.

```
using (var pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
{
    var up = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(pc, "domainUserName");
    var authorizationGroups = up.GetAuthorizationGroups();

    foreach (var group in authorizationGroups)
    {
        if (group.Name == null)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(group.Name);
        }
        claims.Add(
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, group.Name)
        );
    }
}
```

Tried changing

```
var authorizationGroups = up.GetAuthorizationGroups();
```

to

```
var authorizationGroups = up.GetAuthorizationGroups().ToList();
```

With no change.

I've noticed that calling `up.GetGroups()` instead of `up.GetAuthorizationGroups()` seems to works fine, at least dozens of times by logging in.

My question is what is to use `UserPrincipal.GetAuthorizationGroups` method and what is the reason of some null groups in the result.

Answer (score 0):

[The documentation for `GetAuthorizationGroups()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.userprincipal.getauthorizationgroups) says:

> This function only returns groups that are security groups; distribution groups are not returned.

And that it returns

> null if the user does not belong to any groups.

`GetGroups()` will return both security groups and distribution groups. So if the user is a member of only distribution groups and not security groups, then `GetGroups()` will return results and `GetAuthorizationGroups()` will not.

Comment: Sure, but

`A collection of Principal objects that contain the groups of which the user is a member, or null if the user does not belong to any groups.`

So it returns a collection of Principal objects OR null if user doesn't belong to any group. It doesn't explain why some of the Principal objects are null.

Comment: Oh I see, I misunderstood. Are the users a member of groups from an external domain that possibly don't exist anymore? Open an affected user in AD Users and Computers and see if the Member Of tab contains any unresolved SIDs.

Comment: Actually I'm not sure if there is a scenario where the Member Of tab could show an unresolved SID. I'll have to give this some thought.

Comment: These groups are mostly random. They can appear as full object on next `GetAuthorizationGroups()` execute.

Comment: "on next GetAuthorizationGroups() execute" for the exact same user?

Comment: Yes, for the same user. I'll try to investigate later these group, but I don't think they're external. Sometime even `Domain users` were missing.